# Seleniumbase checkout bot script isn't running fast enough

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots, checkout, seleniumbase

I need help getting this checkout bot script written in seleniumbase to run faster. I want it to buy anything new posted to a website where things sell out in seconds, which basically means there is a bot faster than mine because I keep getting beat. I have it refreshing the page a few times a second looking for newly posted items. Maybe there is a better way to do this than check for new href links on the main page than writing to file? Or maybe seleniumbase isn't the fastest way to do this?

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
import time

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def save_urls_to_file(self, url_list, file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'a') as file:  # Use 'a' (append) mode instead of 'w' (write) mode
            for url in url_list:
                file.write(url + '\n')

    def read_urls_from_file(self, file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            return [line.strip() for line in file]

    def get_all_href_links(self):
        elements = self.find_elements('a')
        return [element.get_attribute('href') for element in elements if element.get_attribute('href')]

    def search_for_new_urls(self, main_url, file_path, processed_file_path):
        self.open(main_url)
        all_urls = self.get_all_href_links()

        # Filter out already processed URLs
        processed_urls = self.read_urls_from_file(processed_file_path)
        new_urls = list(set(all_urls) - set(processed_urls))

        if new_urls:
            self.save_urls_to_file(new_urls, file_path)
            with open(processed_file_path, 'a') as processed_file:
                for new_url in new_urls:
                    processed_file.write(new_url + '\n')

            for new_url in new_urls:
                self.run_custom_code(new_url)

    def run_custom_code(self, url):
        self.open(url)
        self.click("div.sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner")
        self.click('div[data-test="continue-to-cart"]')
        self.click('button[data-test="cart-button"]')
        self.type('input[name="email"]', "me@gmail.com", timeout=2)
        self.click('button[data-test="continue-button"]')
        self.type('input[name="fname"]', "John")
        self.type('input[name="lname"]', "Doe")
        self.type('input[data-test="line1"]', "123 Easy")
        self.click('span:contains("Street, Any City, FL, USA")'
        time.sleep(.5)
        self.click('button[data-test="continue-button"]')
        self.click('button[data-test="continue-button"]')
        self.switch_to_frame('//iframe[contains(@name, "privateStripeFrame")]', timeout=2)
        self.find_element('input[name="cardnumber"]').send_keys('4242 4242 4242 4242')
        self.find_element('input[name="exp-date"]').send_keys('00 01')
        self.find_element('input[name="cvc"]').send_keys('346')
        self.switch_to_default_content()
        self.click('button[data-test="continue-button"]')
        self.click('button[data-test="purchase-button"]')        
        time.sleep(2)
        self.save_screenshot("new.png")

    def process_new_urls(self, main_url, file_path, processed_file_path):
        while True:
            self.search_for_new_urls(main_url, file_path, processed_file_path)
            time.sleep(.2)  

    def test_run_script(self):
        main_url = "http://example.com/shop"  
        file_path = "/home/urls.txt"  
        processed_file_path = "/home/processed_urls.txt"  

        self.process_new_urls(main_url, file_path, processed_file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyTestClass().test_run_script()
```

I tried removing `time.sleep()` but the `.5` needs to be in there or it hangs up. I also tried waiting on the element to load but that doesn't work. It's just a limitation of the site.

Answer (score 0):

With SeleniumBase, there are some ways you may be able to speed up your tests.

Here are some pytest command-line options that you should know about:

- `--pls=none` --> Set `pageLoadStrategy` to `"none"`: This strategy causes Selenium to return immediately after the initial HTML content is fully received by the browser.
- `--sjw` --> Skip JS Waits, such as `wait_for_ready_state_complete()`.

Those may help, but it may lead to test flakiness if you use raw selenium commands mixed in.

To remove possible flakiness from that speed-up, swap lines like this:

```py
self.find_element('input[name="cvc"]').send_keys('346')
```

with this instead:

```py
self.type('input[name="cvc"]', '346')
```

But, you may also find that using the built-in JS methods are a little faster. So instead of using this:

```py
self.type(selector, text)
```

you may use this instead:

```py
self.js_type(selector, text)
```

And there's also a `js_click()` method:

```py
self.js_click(selector)
```

There's also `--headless` mode, which can speed up tests:

```bash
pytest --headless
```

After combining all those changes, you should expect a nice speed boost on your script if done properly.

Comment: Could you give me the correct syntax for using the self.js_type(selector, text) for one of the lines? I tried this and it didn't work self.js_click('button[data-test="continue-button"]')

Comment: js_click has the same args as click. js_type has the same args as type. Try the Recorder to autogenerate the correct selectors: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/recorder_mode.md

Comment: Sorry its the js_type that isn't working i.e. self.js_type('input[name="fname"]', "Joe")

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I updated all the clicks with self.js_click which helped a lot. I wish I knew why when I update to self.js_type the text is never entered and the script fails. . If you have any ideas of why that may be going on with that please let me know.